# Maintain sessionscope between pages redirect?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

How can I maintain a `SessionScoped` object between redirects?
I have a main page which accesses a `Stateless` bean.

I also have a button which is doing a redirect (`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/to/my/sevlet");`) to a specific path, and by this invoking the webservlet.
The webservlet itself creates some contition-based response, but that should not matter at the moment.

The problem is: when I'm redirected to the servlet, I lose my session scoped bean property that was set during the initial access of the stateless bean..

How can I maintain a sessionscope between pages switch/redirect?

```
@Stateless
class myStateless {
    @Inject
    MySessionBean sessionBean;

    private doSomething() {
        sessionBean.setSessionProperty(true);
    }
}


@SessionScoped
class MySessionBean {

    Boolean sessionProperty = false;
}


@WebServlet
class MyWebServlet {
    doGet(..) {
        out.println("session property status is" + String.valueOf(sessionBean.isSessionProperty()); //always false
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the Servlet gets a reference to that session scoped bean? Is the Servlet in the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the setup is fine. I just made a reference call to a no-session scoped var.